# How do I configure an Exchange Receive connector to resolve names as trusted?

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2013

There are two ways outlook will display an email address:

```
John Doe <jdoe@company.com>
```

or

```
John Doe
```

The implication of the latter is that it comes from an internal organization or within the Exchange network.  The other implies a spoof, or untrusted source.

How do I configure a receive connector so that it resolves all Authoritative Domains as trusted?